# Format data content in Tableviewcell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How it should look like.

[image: How it should look like]

How it currently look like.

[image: How it currently looks like]

I'm trying to display information on my tableview cell.
The first cell information on the image above looks good, but only when the table view is on edit mode - and I only want the same display in normal mode for all my cells.

Here is my code below
//cellForRow method

```
var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: celliD)

cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell?.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell?.accessoryView = nil
cell?.tintColor = UIColor.cmoOrangeColor
cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
cell?.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

let animalEntity = self.newSaleSelectedAnimalsManagedObject[indexPath.row] as? AnimalEntity
cell?.textLabel?.attributedText = AnimalFacade.animalTitleAttributedText(animalEntity: animalEntity!, withHolding: false)

cell?.detailTextLabel?.attributedText = AnimalFacade.animalDetails()

return cell!
```

//textLabel formating data

```
class func animalTitleAttributedText(animalEntity: AnimalEntity, withHolding: Bool) -> NSMutableAttributedString  {

    //AttributedText
    let attributedTitle = NSDictionary(object: UIFont.tableViewCellTitle as Any, forKey: NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying) as? [String : Any]
    let attributedSubtitle = NSDictionary(object: UIFont.tableViewCellSubtitle as Any, forKey: NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying) as? [String : Any]

    //TextLabel
    let titleAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()


    //officialTag
    let officialTag = animalEntity.officialTag //UK 123456 123456
    let mgtTag = animalEntity.managementTag //WER3456
    let age = DateUtil.calculateAge(dateTime: animalEntity.dob! as Date) //13 y
    let animalCategory = animalEntity.animalTag //Heifer Calf
    let breed = animalEntity.breed //AB

    titleAttributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: officialTag! + "\n", attributes: attributedTitle))
    titleAttributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Mgmt Tag: \(mgtTag!), \(age), \(animalCategory!), \(breed!) \n", attributes: attributedSubtitle))

    return titleAttributedText
}
```

//detailLabel formatting data

```
class func animalDetails() -> NSMutableAttributedString {

    let attributedSubtitle = NSDictionary(object: UIFont.tableViewCellSubtitle as Any, forKey: NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying) as? [String : Any]

    //detailsLabel
    let detailsAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()

    let price = "1234.85"
    let lotNumber = "TREPOU123"

    detailsAttributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: price + "\n\n", attributes: attributedSubtitle))
    detailsAttributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: lotNumber, attributes: attributedSubtitle))

    return detailsAttributedText
}
```

Comment: try to use some constraints

Comment: I think you need to make the Custom cell with required components and gives needed constraints to each component as @kkiermasz told.

Comment: Can you add comparison screenshots of how it is looking now and how it should look?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri - I just edited the the question and inserted the two pictures of how it should look like and how its like currently.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani - Im not using a storyboard - will that be possible?

Comment: I suggest you use a custom cell for that with labels for each element.